# Angular Material Import and Compile

Tags: compilation, angular-material

[image]

[image]

[image]

My app run fine until yesterday.... today I have difficult to import and compile:
My app did run fine with angular material and rxjs  but today visual studio can't import module (I import the module manually with cut and copy or with [crtl]+[.]).
Then a compilation problem come in my server trace... it seems that angular material is not installed....

here my package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
```

Please help me! Thanks friends!

Comment: It's probably because you're missing an import declaration for `MatSelectModule` (from the `@angular/material/select` entry point) for the `<mat-select>` component.

Comment: I solve fix angular release 8.0.0. Visual studio and compiler run fine... I will try fix new version for single module... I fixed all Angular to last version for all component....

Comment: I will read the documentation about last component version 10.*